# Trying to copy file from desktop to usr/share/audacious/skins using terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: command-line

I have a folder called `grey` on my desktop.  I want to either copy or move it to `usr/share/audacious/skins` and it keeps telling me there is no such file or directory.  It's there, on the desktop, why does it keep telling me it's not.

I tried this:

```
noyfb@noyfb-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo cp home/noyfb/desktop/Grey usr/share/audacious/Grey
[sudo] password for noyfb: 
cp: cannot stat `home/noyfb/desktop/Grey': No such file or directory
```

then this

```
noyfb@noyfb-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo cp /home/noyfb/desktop/Grey /usr/share/audacious/Grey
cp: cannot stat `/home/noyfb/desktop/Grey': No such file or directory
```

then this

```
noyfb@noyfb-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo mv /home/noyfb/desktop/Grey /usr/share/audacious/Skins/Grey
mv: cannot stat `/home/noyfb/grey': No such file or directory
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/440147/edit) your question and add output of command `ls -l /home/noyfb/Desktop`.

Comment: linux commands are **case-sensitive**.

Comment: @ Avinash Raj - Thanks I didn't realize the commands are case-sensitive.

Comment: @ Danatela - Sorry I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux files and folders name are case-sensitive. As [souravc](https://askubuntu.com/users/127327/souravc) suggested, the name of the desktop folder is `Desktop`, not desktop. So you should be doing:

```
sudo cp /home/noyfb/Desktop/Grey /usr/share/audacious/Skins/ -r
```

Note the `-r` in the command, it is used when you want to recursively copy files. This is needed since you say, `Grey` is a directory, you can omit `-r`, when the source is not a directory. Also check if your folder name is `Grey` or `grey`.

Comment: @NYB: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Check `desktop` is a typo. It should be `Desktop`. Try to copy as

```
sudo cp -r /home/noyfb/Desktop/Grey /usr/share/audacious/Skins/
```

or to move

```
sudo mv /home/noyfb/Desktop/Grey /usr/share/audacious/Skins/
```

Also check, the folder is `grey` or `Grey`. You mentioned it differently in your question.

`-r` is necessary, thanks to @jobin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, it worked.  I didn't realize it was case sensitive.

Comment: you may [accept one of the answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/127327) at your convenience, it will indicate your problem is solved. read [this also](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)